# mediaplayer seekto online video,can not play

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

when mediaplayer play online video(video is big),I drag progress,progress is 50,and video loading stream is 30,when I use play.seekto(50)，I find stream stopping load ,video can not play,when video is smaller，This phenomenon does not occur，when video is bigger，this phenomeno occur, I don not konw what reason,seek help

Answer (score 0):

You have to use scaling. progress bar 50 is like 50% of video. Depending on the streaming protocol used, get the length of the video (on demand case) and convert 50% of that length to ms as seekTo takes ms as the argument.

Comment: I'm in milliseconds as the argument,I did not use player.seekto(50)